# Using Powershell, how can I export and delete csv rows, where a particular value is *not found* in a *different* csv?

Tags: powershell, csv, search, export

I have two files. One is called allper.csv

```
institutiongroup,studentid,iscomplete
institutionId=22343,123,FALSE
institutionId=22343,456,FALSE
institutionId=22343,789,FALSE
```

The other one is called actswithpersons.csv

```
abc,123;456
def,456
ghi,123
jkl,123;456
```

**Note**: The actswithpersons.csv does not have headers - they are going to be added in later via an excel power query so don't want them in there now. The actswithpersons csv columns are delimited with commas - there are only two columns, and the second one contains multiple personids - again Excel will deal with this later.

I want to remove all rows from allper.csv where the personid doesn't appear in actswithpersons.csv, and export them to another csv. So in the desired outcome, allper.csv would look like this

```
institutiongroup,studentid,iscomplete
institutionId=22343,123,FALSE
institutionId=22343,456,FALSE
```

and the export.csv would look like this

```
institutiongroup,studentid,iscomplete
institutionId=22343,789,FALSE
```

I've got as far as the below, which will put into the shell whether the personid is found in the actswithpersons.csv file.

```
$donestuff = (Get-Content .\ActsWithpersons.csv | ConvertFrom-Csv); $ids=(Import-Csv .\allper.csv);foreach($id in $ids.personid) {echo $id;if($donestuff -like "*$id*" )
{
   echo 'Contains String'
}
else
{
   echo 'Does not contain String'
}}
```

However, I'm not sure how to go the last step, and export & remove the unwanted rows from allper.csv

I've tried (among many things)

```
$donestuff = (Get-Content .\ActsWithpersons.csv | ConvertFrom-Csv);
Import-Csv .\allper.csv |
    Where-Object {$donestuff -notlike $_.personid} |
        Export-Csv -Path export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This took a really long time and left me with an empty csv. So, if you can give any guidance, please help.

Comment: Please provide an exact copy of your `actswithpersons.csv`, as we have it right now, the Csv has no headers and also is first delimited by comma and then delimited by semicolon  so what is the actual delimiter

Comment: See note - the second csv does not have headers.

Answer (score 1):

Since your *actswithpersons.csv* doesn't have headers, in order for you to import as csv, you can specify the `-Header` parameter in either `Import-Csv` or `ConvertFrom-Csv`; with the former cmdlet being the better solution.

With that said, you can use any header name for those 2 columns then filter by the given column name (*ID in this case*) after your import of *allper.csv* using `Where-Object`:

```bash
$awp = (Import-Csv -Path '.\actswithpersons.csv' -Header 'blah','ID').ID.Split(';')
Import-Csv -Path '.\allper.csv' | Where-Object -Property 'Studentid' -notin $awp
```

This should give you:

```
institutiongroup    studentid iscomplete
----------------    --------- ----------
institutionId=22343 789       FALSE
```

If you're looking to do it with `Get-Content` you can split by the delimiters of `,` and `;`. This should give you just a single row of values which you can then compare the entirety of variable (`$awp`) using the same filter as above which will give you the same results:

```
$awp = (Get-Content -Path '.\actswithpersons.csv') -split ",|;" 
Import-Csv -Path '.\allper.csv' | Where-Object -Property 'Studentid' -notin $awp
```